# I've unpacked it...how can I count the columns?

Tags: perl

I am using unpack to parse some text files w/ some columns. Each text file is different and has a different number of columns. How can I count the columns so I don't get errors? Right now I am using 0..5 but if the text file has 3 columns then I get an error: "Use of uninitialized value in substitution...". Thx!

```
open (PARSE,"<$temp") or die $!;

my @template = map {'A'.length} <PARSE> =~ /(\S+\s*)/g; 

next unless @template;
$template[-1] = 'A*';# set the last segment to be slurpy

my $template = "@template";

my @data;

while (<PARSE>) {
    push @data, [unpack $template, $_]
}

for my $dat (@data){ # for each row

    for(0..5){ # for each column in that row
    $dat->[$_]=~s/^\s+//g;
          $dat->[$_]=~s/\s+$//g; 
    print $dat->[$_].',';
    }
    print "\n";

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With languages like Perl, Python, Ruby, etc., you rarely need to stoop to the level of subscripts when iterating over an array:

```
for my $cell (@$dat){
    # Work with $cell rather than $dat->[$_].
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably easier and cleaner to use [`Tie::File`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html) so that you don't have to read everything into memory, but here's one way that uses the `@data` list you set up:

```
my $dataFirstLine = $data[0];
chomp($dataFirstLine);
my @dataColumns = split("\t", $dataFirstLine); # assumes delimiter is tab, replace with escaped delimiter of choice
my $dataColumnCount = scalar @dataColumns;
print "number of columns: $dataColumnCount\n";
```

Comment: Tie::File is never the solution for using *less* memory. `last if $. == 5;` would avoid extra work here.